# Using static folder in Flask for multiple images

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, flask

I'm currently saving two matplotlib graphs to /static folder on a Flask application.

However, when they render in HTML. They both render the first image only. Not two separate images as I would expect.

```
name_img_1 = 'static/1.png?%d' % time.time()
name_img_2 = 'static/2.png?%d' % time.time()

plt.plot( 'Time stamp 1', 'pred1', data=data, linestyle='-', marker='o')
plt.title(' classifier 1')
plt.axhline(y=0.55,label='Threshold (=0.55)')
plt.legend()
plt.savefig(name_img_1,format='png')

plt.plot( 'Time stamp 1', 'pred2', data=data, linestyle='-', marker='o')
plt.title(' classifier 1')
plt.axhline(y=0.55,label='Threshold (=0.72)')
plt.legend()
plt.savefig(name_img_2,format='png')




return render_template("hello.html",user_image=name_img_1,user_image_2=name_img_3,form=form)
```

HTML code

```
<img src="{{ user_image }}" alt="User Image">
<img src="{{ user_image_2 }}" alt="User Imageq23">
```

I've tried creating two separate static folders and subdirectories but neither work.

[Full code snippets](https://gist.github.com/FMCumhaill/20c5c4e3a00838724e0ee350c5abb794)

Answer (score 1):

In your render_template statement you pass along the wrong name for user_image_2.  As there is no name_image_3, jinja just ignores it

```
return render_template("hello.html",user_image=name_img_1,user_image_2=name_img_3,form=form)
```

Try

```
return render_template("hello.html",user_image=name_img_1,user_image_2=name_img_2,form=form)
```